# sql query to select a specific cell in excel

Tags: java, excel, jdbc-odbc

```
Open_YYYY     Open_MM   MetricMonth     BaseTXN_Issued    AllTXN_Issued
2013            4        Apr-2013           24990                42179
2013            5        May-2013           37049                58037
2013            6        Jun-2013           33491                54869
2013            7        Jul-2013           34359                62047
```

I have the information above in an Excel file and I want to select and output just the value for the `AllTXN_Issued` for Jul-2013 as the total for last month's transactions. How do I do this in Java after connecting the Excel spreadsheet using jdbc-odbc connection?

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it works in all platforms.

```
Fillo fillo=new Fillo();
Connection connection=fillo.getConnection("C:\\Test.xlsx");
String strQuery="Select * from Sheet1 where ID=100";
Recordset recordset=connection.executeQuery(strQuery);

while(recordset.next()){
System.out.println(recordset.getField("Details"));
}

recordset.close();
connection.close();
```

http://www.codoid.com/products/view/2/29

Comment: Please also check this one...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21808864/fillo-library-to-read-data-from-excel-unable-to-configure

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me. It assumes that the [MetricMonth] column in Excel contains text values (rather than true dates formatted as MMM-yyyy), but it should at least give you the general idea.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class jdbcTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" + 
                    "Dbq=C:\\__tmp\\Book1.xlsx;");

            PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement(
                    "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE [MetricMonth] = ?");
            s.setString(1, "Jul-2013");
            s.execute();
            ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet();
            if (rs!=null) {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println(rs.getInt("AllTXN_Issued"));
                }
            }
            s.close();

            conn.close();
        } catch( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Fillo fillo=new Fillo();
Connection connection=fillo.getConnection("C:\\Test.xlsx");//Path to your excel workbook
String strQuery="Select * from SheetName where Open_YYYY = 2013 and MetricMonth like '%Jul%'";
Recordset recordset=connection.executeQuery(strQuery);

while(recordset.next()){
System.out.println(recordset.getField("AllTXN_Issued"));
}

recordset.close();
connection.close();
```