# FILLO library to read data from Excel (unable to configure)

Tags: java, excel

I want to read/write from/to excel file and I searched through Internet, I got [FILLO](http://www.codoid.com/products/view/2/29) library. I just import that .jar file into my netbeans Project

Please check the image

[image: FILLO Library Error]

I dont know, if I'm missing anything. 
Anyone who know, Please help me.

Comment: You'are probably missing an import, can't tell you which one as that library jar was not behind some registration... EDIT: add `import Fillo.*` before your line 41

Comment: yes, I didn't add that before.. but after adding, it gives error
"Package Fillo doesn't exist"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following it worked for me,

1. Use the latest version of Fillo jar which is fillo-1.18.jar
2. And import following

   ```
   import Exception.FilloException;
   import Fillo.Connection;
   import Fillo.Fillo;
   import Fillo.Recordset;
   ```

Recordset, Connection are include in jdk and fillo but with some different characteristics